# How to move item back to original folder

Tags: sitecore-client

Is there a way to move items back to the original folder? I'm asking this because I accidentally moved multiple items from different folders to a single folder. And now, problem is that I could not figure out which item belongs to which folder.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't exist such a functionality out of the box. But you can check in your logs what items were move. 
You will see something like in the logs file:

```
33268 17:09:46 INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\admin): Move item: master:/sitecore/content/Website/Error, language: en, version: 1, id: {94ABEF89-B177-4F72-AA5A-AE8A8AEA4D8F} to sitecore://master/{09503406-D423-445B-B82A-AD9F4623F524}?lang=en&ver=1
```